# Github/Gitlab Repository overall score

Tags: github, gitlab

I am trying to think about a service that will give you a score for any git repository in GitHub/Gitlab to let you understand better the considerations you need to take in order to use any open-source code. Basically, there are a lot of philosophic debates about why this repo is better than the other, of course beyond the obvious metrics that you see on the repo page. It looks like something everyone in our field would love to have, so, I thought I will find several tools that do this, but, actually, I didn't find any that take all the available properties and put them in an equation and output number. So, those are the properties I thought that would be relevant:

- Contributors strength
- Tech stack adoption
- Overall popularity
- Contribution
- Commits
- Branches
- Active discussions
- Community
- Stars
- Forks
- Watch
- Security
- Status of third-party dependencies
- Static code analysis grade
- Time spent
- Activity intervals
- Test coverage
- Issues
- Pull requests
- Releases
- Sponsors
- Bakers
- Twitter sentiment
- License

I saw some works in this field, like:
[Scoring Popularity in GitHub](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.04865.pdf)

Do you familiar with such a tool, or, want to build something like that? I would like to hear.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly opinion-based, and isn't strictly a question about programming, so it isn't really fit for Stack Overflow ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), but I think the [Core Infrastructure Initiative Best Practices Program](https://bestpractices.coreinfrastructure.org/en) from the Linux Foundation is worth mentioning.

It doesn't scan a repository, but project maintainers can self-certify that the project meets a variety of scenarios that are part of `passing`, `silver`, or `gold` criteria:

- Having a detailed description of the project and how to use it (passing)
- Explaining how others can contribute to the project (passing)
- The projects license is approved by the Open Source Initiative (OSI) (passing)
- Must clearly define the project's governance model (silver)
- Must have a documented roadmap (silver)
- There must be smaller tasks identified that and new or casual contributor could complete (gold)
- Must have had a security review within the last 5 years (gold)

Here's an example for one of my projects that has a "passing" level: https://bestpractices.coreinfrastructure.org/en/projects/2840